# W11 How to ensure USB has no power in hibernation

Tags: usb, windows-11, power-management

My mouse and keyboard are being powered while Windows 11 is hibernating. They are connected to a USB port that came with the PC case. Is there a way to switch power off?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. USB always ON is a BIOS function.

Comment: "_Is there a way to switch power off?_" - maybe, maybe not... it likely depends entirely on your motherboard. Why do you want the USB power to be turned off? Does the PC wake/resume if you press a key / mouse button?